# How to count the number of words in each line of an array of strings using linq extension methods

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I have an array of strings, like in the bellow example:

```
string[] words = { "C#", "I like C#", 
                   "My string is this", 
                   "Just words", "Delegates and Linq"};
```

To count the words in each of the strings it's pretty straight forward, one can use `words.Split(' ').Length`, and a `foreach` creating an array containing the number of words in each string, or place the individual counts directly into an array, let's call it an array of counts, with query syntax:

```
var countWordsArray = from s in words select s.TrimEnd(' ').Split(' ').Length;
```

What I would like to do instead is to use extension methods, something like:

```
var CountWordsArray = words.Select(s => s...);
```

The hours are long but the day is short, so I'd realy appreciate the help. I'm sure I'm missing something basic but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: `var listaUmCountChars = words.Select(s => s.Split(' ').Length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension method translation:

```
var listaUmCountChars = words.Select(s => s.Split(' ').Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int wordCount = 
    words.Sum((w) => w.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                      .Length);
```

Comment: As `string.Split` returns an array, you should use `Array.Length` rather than `Enumerable.Count`, which would iterate each array unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension method to do the word count too.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int WordCount(this string me)
    {
        return me.Split(' ').Length;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] words = { "C#", "I like C#",
                "My string is this",
                "Just words", "Delegates and Linq"};
        List<int> listaUmCountChars = words.Select(s => s.WordCount()).ToList(); // 1 3 4 2 3
        int totalWordCount = words.Sum(s => s.WordCount()); // 13
    }
}
```